# Installing gnome breaks seamless mode

Tags: gnome, virtualbox

I am working on Ubuntu with virtualbox (on my mac). I have just installed gnome, and it broke a lot of features, among wich the very nice feature of seamless mode. How can I retrieve it ?

Comment: @Takkat It is Ubuntu 12.04, and VirtualBox 4.1.23. The seamless mode is eveb not accessible from the menu bar's item 'view'(colored in an non-clickable grey). Does it mean anythink to you ?

Comment: @Takkat The "Auto-resize Guest Display" is set (checked) but I can't modify it...like the seamless mode item (colored in an non-clickable grey)

Comment: @Takkat, in fact I suppressed in the virtual box's configuration, the IDE, but now I can't import a new iso image. I don't really understand anything from virtualbox

Comment: I don't know how to do this from MacOS but the name of the virtual box GUI should be "Virtual Box Manager" called with `VirtualBox`. You may also be able to access settings with HOST+S keys.

Answer (score 0):

Both *"Seamless Mode"* and *"Auto-Resize Guest Display"* are advanced features from Virtual Box that are provided from the Guest Additions. These may have been deactivated and need to be reinstalled.

See this questions on details how to install Virtual Box guest additions in Ubuntu:

- [How do I install Guest Additions in a VirtualBox VM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox/22745#22745)

Usually the guest additions CD will be mounted from the menu entry *Devices -> Install Guest Additions* in Virtual Box Manager. For a manual installation the guest additions CD can also be found in Mac OS as follows:

> you can find this file in the application bundle of VirtualBox. (Right click on the VirtualBox icon in Finder and choose Show Package Contents. There it is located in the Contents/MacOS folder.)<sup>[Virtual Box User Manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#idp10352640)</sup>

For recommended procedures to install Virtual Box in MacOS also read more in the [Virtual Box User Manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch02.html#idp9071184).

Comment: Ouahhh, I have lost all my data. I have installed again the image disk and all my data have disappeared, and btw still not possible to install the guest additions...., I have the message 'unable to mount the CD/DVD image /Applications/Virtualbox.app/...'

Comment: Sorry to hear that. There is only a small chance to recover parts of your data after you deleted you virtual disk file when reinstalling Ubuntu.

Comment: That's what I did, I recovered none of them... Thanks anyway